# How to use Keep in Dock option with applications started form the console?

Tags: macos, finder

I tried to use `Keep in Dock` option with a Java application that is started from the command line but when I try to restart the application it will fail - and this is happening because it will start java without any parameters.

There are two ways of starting the application on OS X but both of them fail if you want to use the Keep in Dock option.

- start it using the shell script `olv.sh`
- start the jar file `logview.jar` by clicking on it in Finder.

In case you want to debug, the application is http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer but I know that the same problem applies for other apps too.

How can I solve the problem so I can start the application from Dock and eventually from Finder also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a shell script to invoke the java app with the parameters you need, then wrap it up in an app with [Platypus](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/12046/platypus).

The resultant app can then be put in the Dock like any other app.

I've used it for a variety of tasks, such as popping-up a help screen with a serial number for users to enter for a recalcitrant app which didn't like mass deployment and would ask the user to enter it at first run, to a complicated script which mounted a disk-image of a science textbook's additional media DVD and then ran the associated app to access the content. Platypus even allowed me to roll the disk-image into the final app itself, making deployment easier.

Comment: I don't like the approach, but it's the only one I got so far. Thanks.

Comment: @sorin, @Icon. Y not just [script editor `do shell script`](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#writing-an-applescript-wrapper-mac-os-x)? You can even change the icon....